# Need the simplest way possible to change the background of a header with a photo from MySQL

Tags: php, css, mysql, background-image

I need the simplest way possible to use the photo I've inserted into MySQL through a form      line of code. That part works(I think) and the photo is in the MySQL database in a text format ''photo.jpg''. But I've been struggling on a way to extract it from the database and make it a background of a header through mysql_fetch_assoc I'm using to display the other data. It works well for the other data, but I can't figure it out for the pic... If anyone has a way to do it, for it to be a simple and as short as possible

```
<header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('assets/img/post-bg.jpg')">
```

This is the code for the current header with a fixed image instead of the changeable one which I need

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/css-database-queries/ , did this solve your problem?

Comment: No, don't use CSS or JS database queries, they're a massive security risk.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an inline echo:

```
<header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('assets/img/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>')">
```

Obviously change $row and image to the values that you are using in your script.